Using Visual Studio 2022, is it possible to change the default path where the terminal opens?
I am using VS 2022. When I click View > Terminal it opens Powershell in the solution's root directory.

Is it possible to change this default path to anther customized location within the solution?

It looks like you are using PowerShell, so try specifying the -StartInPath flag are part of the arguments to the PowerShell executable (after the Enter-VsDevShell cmdlet call).  Go to Tools → Options → Environment → Terminal and find your profile you are using and modify it like so:

In this example I set mine to C:\ and PowerShell opened up to that location. This cmdlet isn't very well documented, but I did find one website with some information, including this -StartInPath option.
